# How to express variable through other in SAGE

Tags: sage, substitution

Is there way to express mathematical expression through variable defined earlier in SAGE?

For example if I have variable `a = b + c`, I want SAGE rewrite expression `b + c + d` as `a + d`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, substituting such expressions is a nontrivial thing if you don't know what part of the expression tree you want.  See Richard Fateman's comments [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sage-devel/iXsU5FasB38).

The core of the problem is that even the command that *would* do what you want is not about strings, but expressions.

```
sage: var("a b c d")
(a, b, c, d)
sage: (a+d).subs({a:b+c})
b + c + d
sage: (b+c+d).subs({b+c:a})
b + c + d
```

So you will have to use a "wildcard".

```
sage: w0 = SR.wild(0)
sage: (b+c+d).subs({b+c+w0:a+w0})
a + d
```

For more information, see

```
sage: x.match?
sage: SR.wild?
```

in the interactive shell or notebook.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [calculus](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/calculus/calculus.html), you can express d as variable with

```
a = var('a'); b+c
```

or like a function of b and c variable

Comment: Yes, sure, but my question is how can I simplify expression (i.e. `b + c + d`) using definition of `a` and gain `a + d`. It is just simple example.

Comment: Use simplify as you see in http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/symbolic/expression.html

Comment: Seems it does not work:
`sage: var("a b c d")

(a, b, c, d)

sage: a = var("a");b+c

b + c

sage: (b + c + d).simplify()

b + c + d`